# Android Studio: USB device not recognized as Android device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to test an application on my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S8), but I cannot see it in the available devices menu in Android Studio. I can see it as a USB device is not recognized as an Android device.
[image]

This seems strange, considering that I have enabled developer mode on my phone. Furthermore, when I check to see that the driver for the device updated to the latest version, it shows that it is updated correctly.
[image]

Comment: You have to allow usb debugging or PDANet to install device properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure you did everything right, but you are still facing this problem, try to run this command in cmd:

```
adb kill-server
```

After that reconnect your phone and run:

```
adb start-server
```

And check if your phone is in devices lists by run:

```
adb devices
```

(In some cases you should restart the Android studio)